# How to make body flying

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am trying to make a body flying

is there any way to change gravity or hold the circle levitating?

Here is the code i'm using:

```
public class Fly extends Enemy {

     .....
   protected void defineEnemy() {
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(getX(),getY());
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2body=world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(6/Advanture.PPM);
    b2body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);


}

 @Override
public void update(float dt) {
   stateTime +=dt;
   b2body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(-1,0));
   setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth()/2, 1); 


  }

......    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the way of changing gravity.

So, this is done by using `b2body.setGravityScale(float number);`

If you want to make the body less affected by gravity, it should be `b2body.setGravityScale(1/100);`

So it depends on number, you can let the character be affected by gravity however much you want.